# In xslt, How can I create a child node to an xml element with the same namespace prefix as other nodes under the same element

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml body that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ns:Books xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:dg="urn" xmlns:ns="another urn">
    <ns:Title>
        <ns2:Author>Poe</ns2:Author>
        <ns2:Genre>Horror</ns2:Genre>
    </ns:Title>
</ns:Books>
```

And this is what I have so far for my xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="//*[local-name()='Title']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="./*[local-name()='Author']"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="./*[local-name()='Price']">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="./*[local-name()='Price']"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:element name="Price">
                            UNKNOWN
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:copy-of select="./*[local-name()='Genre']"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is what the xslt outputs

```
<ns:Books xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:dg="another urn" xmlns:ns="an urn">
    <ns:Title>
        <ns2:Author>Poe</ns2:Author>
        <Price>UNKNOWN</Price>
        <ns2:Genre>Horror</ns2:Genre>
    </ns:Title>
</ns:Books>
```

But I need the output to be

```
<ns:Books xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:dg="another urn" xmlns:ns="an urn">
    <ns:Title>
        <ns2:Author>Poe</ns2:Author>
        <ns2:Price>UNKNOWN</ns2:Price>
        <ns2:Genre>Horror</ns2:Genre>
    </ns:Title>
</ns:Books>
```

The problem is my namespaces are different in my xmls.
Is there a way that i can create the `<price>` node with the same namespace prefix as the elements under `<Title>`?

Comment: Please post a **reproducible** example. The input you show will produce nothing except an error because the "ns2" prefix is not bound to a namespace. Likewise your expected. output.

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure that the `Price` element is bound to the same namespace of the first child of `Title` by using the `@namespace` attribute and applying the `namespace-uri()` of the first child element relative from `Title`:

```
<xsl:element name="Price" namespace="{*[1]/namespace-uri()}">
```

But it may not serialize with the same `ns2` namespace prefix.

If you *really* care about it having the same namespace-prefix, then could try splitting the `name()` value and using the prefix, if it exists:

```
<xsl:element name="{*[1]/replace(name(), '(\w+:)?.+', '$1')}Price" namespace="{*[1]/namespace-uri()}">
```

It seems like the template you had matching on `Book` should be matching on `Title`. Also, no need for `./` everywhere. The default axis is the child axis, so just provide a relative XPath:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='Title']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*[local-name()='Author']"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="*[local-name()='Price']">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="*[local-name()='Price']"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:element name="{replace(*[1]/name(), '(\w+:)?.+', '$1')}Price" namespace="{*[1]/namespace-uri()}">
                        <xsl:text>UNKNOWN</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*[local-name()='Genre']"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: But here is the problem, With the first example, it will only grab the first namespace, and not add the prefix, and with the second example, it will only grab the namespace prefix of the parent element, when the namespace prefix of the created node needs to match that of the new nodes sibling elements

Comment: You can select the namespace and prefix from the sibling elements. It wasn't exactly clear what you needed, and your input XML is not well-formed, so harder to test. Describe what element you want to select from in the question and fix the example XML so that it can be transformed.

Comment: So I need the <Price> element to have the same namespace prefix as the first element under <Title>. All the elements under <Title> should all have the same namespace prefix as there are other parts of my application that look at the namespace prefix of nodes.